# Spark Streaming programming

Tags: python, scala, spark-streaming

The problem at hand could be summarized as follows:

I have a set of `user_id`s, and I start a Spark Streaming task, receiving stream data and compute some cumulative statistics of some `user_id`, it keeps running all the time.

Every 60 seconds, I need to check the statistics of those `user_id`s, and write them into a file, and then change the set of `user_id`s to another new set of ones, and repeat this process along the way.

I'm new to Spark Streaming jobs, hope I could get some hints of the best implementation of the above idea, pseudo-code preferred.
Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the window transformation of apache spark streaming and the time interval of the window will be 60 seconds, If you want to explore more on that pls check below links

https://blog.knoldus.com/2015/06/24/stateful-transformation-on-dstream-in-apache-spark-with-example-of-wordcount/

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#window-operations